# wp_upload_bits Upload Specific Sizes Only

Tags: filters, attachments, images, uploads

For images uploaded using this code, I want to only upload the full-size image and the thumbnail (whereas for images uploaded through site, I want all sizes). However, I can't figure out how to make it only upload the full-size/thumbnail as this code currently only uploads an image with all sizes:

```
$attachment = array(
            'post_author' => "test", 
            'post_date' => $date,
            'post_date_gmt' => gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date) ),
            'post_title' => "just some title", 
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'ping_status' => 'closed',
            'post_name' => "just some picture",                                           
            'post_modified' => $date,
            'post_modified_gmt' => gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date) ),
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'guid' =>  $upload['url'],
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_excerpt' => '',
            'post_content' => ''
        );

        $upload = wp_upload_bits( "picture.jpg", null, file_get_contents("picture.jpg") );
        if ( $upload['error'] )
            echo "Failed uploading: " . $upload['error'];
```

The only way I can think of doing this is to return the `attachment_id` and then `unlink` all sizes except the full size and the thumbnail, but that seems very messy. What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how you can limit the image upload size

function fineima() {
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    wp_upload_bits($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']));
  }
  echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
  ';
}
function fineFileUploaderRenderer() {
  ob_start();
  fineimageUpload();
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('your_file_uploader', 'fineFileUploaderRenderer');
```